# python - filter list by substring of second list

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, filter

I'm trying to remove items within list1 of the same index based on the occurence of a substring in list2.

```
List1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

List2 = ["Remove1", "Remove2", "OtherValue1", "Othervalue2"]
```

Result should be:

```
List1 = ["3", "4"]

List2 = ["OtherValue1", "Othervalue2"]
```

From a logical view:

Check if element in List2 starts with/includes substring "Remove" and if true: remove this entry and entry in List1 with the same index.

I searched a lot of threads & questions but usually they want to compare 2 lists with (partially) identical entries and filter them accordingly. There are numerous ways I could think of performing it from a logical point of view, unfortunately I'm lacking of pythons syntax knowledge to put it together (once I would see the correct code I most likely will say "sure, easy, makes sense" -.-")

Thanks for the help in advance,
Toby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use zip() to zip the two lists into a list of tuples and then iterate through it.

```
>>> List1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
>>> List2 = ["Remove1", "Remove2", "OtherValue1", "Othervalue2"]

>>> result1 = []
>>> result2 = []
>>> for x,y in zip(List1,List2):
...     if "Remove" not in y:
...         result1.append(x)
...         result2.append(y)
>>> result1
['3', '4']
>>> result2
["OtherValue1", "Othervalue2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the conditions remain same. Applying the same logic for better understanding.Simply assign the remaining elements to the same list(here assuming that Remove string comes before OtherValue in these lists).

```
list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
list2 = ["Remove1", "Remove2", "OtherValue1", "Othervalue2"]

for i,j in zip(list1, list2):
    if "Remove" in j:
        list1 = list1[1:]
        list2 = list2[1:]

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def RemoveItems(List1, List2):
    List1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    List2 = ["Remove1", "Remove2", "OtherValue1", "Othervalue2"]
    index = []

    for item in List2:
        if item.startswith('Remove'):
            index.append(List2.index(item))

    index.reverse()

    for item in index:
        del List1[item]
        del List2[item]

    return (List1, List2)

List1, List2 = RemoveItems(List1, List2)

print("List1 : ", List1)
print("List2 : ", List2)
```